# Using tryCatch to record failed i-th iteration

Tags: r

```
ith.error <- NULL

bar <- function(i){
  ith.error <<- append(ith.error,i)
return(ith.error)
}

for(i in c(2,3,5,"p",6)){
  tryCatch(

    {cat(log(i),"\n")}, 

    error=function(e){bar()}   #**

  )

}
```

was trying to record any failed i-th iteration in a for-loop using tryCatch,
the output of `ith.error` should be 4 (in vector format, index position of the input given)

** tried many version on that particular line:

```
ith.error[i] <- i  #version 1 doesn't work
h = bar(i)         #version 2 didn't work too
```

Comment: Your code fails at iteration 1. Consider that `c(2,3,5,"p",6)` is a `character` vector: when you concatenate elements of different kinds, all are coerced to the same type (the "higher" one: a string in this case). Use `list` instead of `c` (and  call `bar(i)` instead of just `bar()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to input `i` to the `bar` function. Also consider that `c(2,3,5,"p",6)` is a `character` vector and you can't apply `log` to any of its elements. Use `list` instead.

```
ith.error <- NULL

bar <- function(i){
  ith.error <<- append(ith.error,i)
return(ith.error)
}

for(i in list(2,3,5,"p",6)){
  tryCatch(

    {cat(log(i),"\n")},     
    error=function(e){bar(i)}   #**

  )

}
ith.error
#[1] "p"
```

Comment: I was just appending to mention that, and you are right with `c`

Comment: You don't want to convert to `numeric`. In that case, you don't have errors, but just a warning. Remove `as.numeric`.

Comment: just simplified